# Docker and Webpack hot reload not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack

Here I would like to use Docker for my future react/webpack app, but I can't configure Webpack and/or docker correctly for the reload to work (webpack-dev-server ).

I don't really understand why, the configuration seems ok to me, maybe my "start" command which is not good ?

Here is the Dockerfile config :

```
FROM node:11-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app

CMD npm start
EXPOSE 8081
```

Here Webpack.config.js :

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: "./src/App.jsx",
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    },
    {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            'style-loader',
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            'css-loader',
            'resolve-url-loader',
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            'sass-loader',
        ]
    }
  ]
},
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  port:8081,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 500, // delay before reloading
    poll: 1000 // enable polling since fsevents are not supported in docker
}
},
plugins: [new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" })]
};
```

Here npm start scripts :

```
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
```

Thank you !

Comment: How you run the container?

Comment: `docker build -t test . `
`docker run -p 8081:8081`

Comment: not build command, the `docker run` command as hot reloading concern with `run` command.

Comment: I put it right after, my docker run command is: `docker run -p 8081:8081 test`

Comment: then how you are expecting hot reloading? how you change file?

Comment: What I'd like is to reload the page every time I save a file, without having to rebuild docker, like if I run the app in webpack-dev-server, but in a docketable container.(Even if a live-reloading)

Comment: Your container has no way to detect files changes without binding them  to the container ones with a volumes, when you build your image, it copy your local files at moment and it'll be the one served when you run a container from it

Answer (score 0):

From the comment, you are not using [binding host volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to the container. you should bind host volume to make hot reloading work.

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/host_app_code/:/app test
```

where `$PWD/host_app_code/` is the path to host files, once you bind this path, your change on the host will effect inside the container and hot reload should work and you will not need to build image every time.

Comment: I should do something like this to bind the host src file? `docker run -it --rm -v ./src -p 8081:8081 test`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Adiii's answer, you will need to use a bind-mount volume so that the files are changed inside the container as you change them on your host, without having to rebuild the image.

I just wanted to add that Docker's getting started tutorial explains using bind-mounts for development. I would definitely recommend to go through that if you haven't, as it can give a deeper understanding of how it works and why this is necessary.

Docker's getting-started tutorial is available on [docker-hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/getting-started):

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it quickly but it doesn't work yet, I think I'll linger a bit more on the tutorial to understand how it works properly, thank you!